# How to reorder coordinate values using the euclidian distance in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, euclidean-distance

I want to reorder the coordinate value based on the euclidean distance .
For example I have coordinates:

```
1 2 
2 1 
1 3
1 9
6 9
3 5
6 8
4 5
7 9
```

I have got euclidean distance of first coordinate with other coordinate:

With the following code:

```
with open("../data comparision project/testfile.txt") as f:

    # for splitting the text file into to lists of list
    my_list = [[x for x in line.strip().split(' ')] for line in f
    index = 0

    # empty list to store distances.
    euclidean_distance_list = []
    for list_of_item in my_list:
        plot1=my_list[0]
        plot2=my_list[index]
        euclidean_distance=math.sqrt((float(plot1[0])-float(plot2[0]))**2 + (float(plot1[1])-float(plot2[1]))**2)
        index=index+1

    # Out of for loop
    sorted_list=sorted(euclidean_distance_list)
    print(sorted_list)
```

This generates the following output:

```
[0.0, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 3.605551275463989, 4.242640687119285, 7.0, 7.810249675906654, 8.602325267042627, 9.219544457292887]
```

Now I want to reorder the original coordinate value based on the these distances such that it will be:

```
1 2
1 3
1 9
2 1
3 5
4 5
6 8
6 9
7 9
```

Can anyone help me with python code.I have caluclated distance but unable to get list with sorted coordinate vlaues.

Comment: How are your values stored? What libraries are you using?

Comment: @FChm coordinte vlaues are in txt file and i have opened and each line of txt file(i.e coordinate) is stored in list.There is a main list containing all list of coordinate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I suggest showing some code to how you loaded the values, stored them in a list and then calculated the euclidian distance.

Comment: is 3rd entry in ordered list a typo? Entry `1 9` is `7` away from 1st entry, while 4th is `1,41`

Comment: Thank you for you responses. I have just updated my question with code.

Answer (score 2):

You want to sort the list based on a custom comparator.

Check out the `key` optional argument to the sort function. You can supply a custom comparator as `key`.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score 1):

To fill in a bit more detail - supposing that you already wrote the function:

```
def euclidean_distance(a, b):
    # does the math and gives the distance between coordinates a and b.
    # If you got the values some other way - better reorganize the code
    # first so that you have a function like this :)
```

We can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html) to make a function for distances from a given point:

```
distance_from_a = functools.partial(euclidean_distance, points[0])
```

and then the rest of the logic is built into Python's native [sorting functionality](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html):

```
sorted(points, key=distance_from_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a custom sort by doing something like this assuming you are using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

def euclidian_distance(a, b):
  return np.linalg.norm(a - b)

coords = np.array([[1,2], 
                   [2,1], 
                   [1,3],
                   [1,9],
                   [6,9],
                   [3,5],
                   [6,8],
                   [4,5],
                   [7,9]])

coords = sorted(coords, key=lambda point: euclidian_distance(point, coords[0]))
print(np.matrix(coords)) # matrix is only for formatting for readability purposes
```

**Output:**

```
[[1 2]
 [1 3]
 [2 1]
 [3 5]
 [4 5]
 [1 9]
 [6 8]
 [6 9]
 [7 9]]
```

*To explain why the above output is different from the OP's. It's because the OP's example output is not actually ordered by distance like they described they wanted.*